# Is it safe to open a file, write to it and NOT close it?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I have quite a large Python(3) script that I'm trying to optimize.
To my understanding when you use `with open(..., ...) as x` you **DON'T** need to use `.close()` at the end of the "with" block (it is automatically closed).

I also know that you **SHOULD** add `.close()` (if you are not using `with`) after you are done manipulating the file, like this:

```
f = open(..., ...)
f.write()
f.close()
```

In an attempt to shove 3 lines (above) into 1 line I tried to change this:

```
with open(location, mode) as packageFile:
    packageFile.write()
```

Into this:

```
open(location, mode).write(content).close()
```

Unfortunately this did not work and I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    one.save("one.txt", sample)
  File "/home/nwp/Desktop/Python/test/src/one.py", line 303, in save
    open(location, mode).write(content).close()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'close'
```

The same line works fine when I remove the *`.close()`* like this:

```
open(location, mode).write(content)
```

Why didn't `open(location, mode).write(content).close()` work and is it safe to omit the `.close()` function?

Comment: You can't "optimize" a script by "shoving" multiple lines together. All you'll end up doing is affecting readability, possibly introducing bugs like this, and making it that much harder for your script to be maintained. Programs are meant to be read by *people* just as much as by machines, and they need to be maintained, not always by the original author. When you try to cram stuff together, it just makes everything that much harder. Sure, method chaining is useful sometimes, as it can prevent the creation of possibly expensive temporary variables, but it's not always worth it in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it safe to omit the .close() function?

In current versions of CPython the file will be closed at the end of the for loop because CPython uses reference counting as its primary garbage collection mechanism but that's an implementation detail, not a feature of the language.

Also directly quoting [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112): `if you ever run this code on a different Python implementation, or if CPython ever abandons reference counting, your write could be arbitrarily delayed or even lost completely.`

> Why didn't open(location, mode).write(content).close() work?

This is because I was trying to call the `.close()` method on the return of `open(location, mode).write(content)`.

Answer (score 1):

> I also know that you **SHOULD** add `.close()` after you are done manipulating the file

Not if you're using `with`.

> Why didn't `open(location, mode).write(content).close()` work

Because instead of trying to close the file, you're trying to close the return value of the `write` method call, which is an integer. You can't close an integer.

> is it safe to omit the `.close()` function?

No. If you ever run this code on a different Python implementation, or if CPython ever abandons reference counting, your write could be arbitrarily delayed or even lost completely.

If you really want to shove this into a single line, you can write a single-line `with` statement:

```
with open(location, mode) as packageFile: packageFile.write(whatever)
```

This is discouraged, but much less discouraged than relying on the file object's finalizer to close the file for you.

Comment: @Tommy: Different Python version.

Comment: the OP tagged 'python' and 'python3', and nowhere in the question do they specify, so this should be made more generic or question should be edited for future users, maybe.

Comment: @Tommy: I would consider the Python 3 tag to specify that they're on Python 3, and the error message specifically says that they're trying to close an integer. In any case, the answer isn't fundamentally different if you're on Python 2 and you end up trying to close `None`.

Comment: well before you answered I spent a lot of time trying to figure out where that error message came from because I couldn't reproduce it, and didn't realize this until you said they were on python3. The first tag was python.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `.` (dot) operator works from left to right. In `a.b`, `b` is a message(method call) passed to `a`. Say

```
a.b.c...
```

reads

```
do b in a and return r1, then
do c in r1 and return r2, then
...
```

Now `open` returns an object that responds to `read` message, but `read` returns a `str`/`bytes` that has no method `close`.

Bdw, **always** use a context manager i.e with `with` in such context. And I wonder what does this have to do with optimization, as you said you are doing this while optimizing a script.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the goal is for one function to occur right after another, however that isn't what is happening here.

open(location, mode) returns a file:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

In the syntax of

```
open(location, mode).write(content)
```

this is actually equivalent to

```
file = open(location, mode)
file.write(content)
```

the open statement becomes a type file which has a function called write().  The reason .close() doesn't work is that the file.write() doesn't have a function called close().  What this is trying to do is file.function().function().

In any case trying to optimize your code by reducing lines will not speed up performance noticeably, the normal with statement should be just as fast.  Unless you are trying to go code golfing which is a whole other subject.

Have a good day!

Comment: thank you for the answer. Do you know you can quote your inline code with ````, like `file.write()`? Also the OP asked whether it is safe to omit `close()`.